# Haddop i trying to run my oozie job but i am unable to run , This is Error

Tags: oozie

I am trying to run my oozie job but i am unable to run ,

This is Error:

```
./bin/oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie/ -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: E0902 : E0902: Exception occured: [User: ubuntu is not allowed to impersonate ubuntu]
```

Could u please tell me exactly what is the issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct proxyuser provided in hadoop core-site.xml. Below properties needs to set in hadoop core-site.xml :

```html
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>HOSTNAME</value>  <!-- put suitable hostname -->
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>  <!-- use correct group here . * is not safe -->
  </property>
```